# Swift Eureka: Adding text value to ButtonRow

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, eureka-forms

Currently, I am getting this result using a ButtonRow by adding a label view to the cell:

[image]

```
<<< ButtonRow("Email") {
            $0.title = $0.tag
            $0.presentationMode = PresentationMode.Show(...)
            }.cellSetup {
                cell, row in

                let text = UILabel(frame: cell.frame)
                text.frame.size.width = 0.909 * currentScreenWidth - 68
                text.frame.origin.x = 68
                text.textColor = UIColor(red: 142/255, green: 142/255, blue: 147/255, alpha: 1)
                text.textAlignment = .Right
                text.text = "fakeEmail@email.com"
                cell.addSubview(text)
 }
```

I am using ButtonRow because it has that little ">" at the end, and it works great when presenting a new view and view controller programmatically.

Using `$0.value = "Some String"` does not work, like it does with other properties.

Is there anyway to do this without having to manually add a label view? It works in all screens, but nevertheless I don't think it's very safe to manually set those parameters.

Answer (score 6):

The implementation of ButtonRow uses UITableViewCellStyle 'default' when initializing the cell object. You can create a subclass of ButtonRow:

```
public final class DetailedButtonRowOf<T: Equatable> : _ButtonRowOf<T>, RowType {
    public required init(tag: String?) {
        super.init(tag: tag)
        cellStyle = .value1
    }
}
public typealias DetailedButtonRow = DetailedButtonRowOf<String>
```

Then you can specify the detailLabelText of the row:

```
<<< DetailedButtonRow("Email") { row in
    row.title = row.tag
    row.presentationMode = .segueName(segueName: "AStoryboardSegue", onDismiss: nil)
}.cellUpdate({ (cell, row) in
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "fakeEmail@email.com"
})
```